# Query in using Callback function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a basic tic-tac-toe game and have created nine paragraph elements arranged in a grid for the same. I've created three functions for checking for winner of X, O and draw. But I am stuck in putting X and O in the boxes. From what I can think of the "this" keyword can put the same in these boxes. The three functions (winnerX, O and draw) are checking for victory and draw and are working fine. Now, I want to pass a fourth function as well that passes on the values of X and O. Can anybody suggest me how to do the same? (the initial value of var xvalue is X.

```js
 
function alternateX (a) {
    
    
    if (xValue === "x") {
        
        xValue = "0";
        a.textContent = xValue;
        a.style.pointerEvents  = "none"; 
    }
    
    else {
    xValue = "x";
        a.textContent = xValue;
    a.style.pointerEvents  = "none";
    } 
}
```

```html
<p class="box1" onclick="boxClick(winnerX, winnerO, draw)">x</p>
```

Comment: Can you reduce that code to the *minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem*? This is too much for what’s probably a simple question.

Comment: I just kept it this way so that there's no confusion. What could be the probable issue that callback is not working the way I want it to?

Answer (score 0):

Screen redraws are typically delayed until the function that causes them completes. So delay the alert.

```js
function handleClick0(){
  document.querySelector('#s0').textContent = 'clicked';
  alert('clicked');
}

function handleClick1(){
  document.querySelector('#s1').textContent = 'clicked';
  setTimeout(function(){alert('clicked')},0);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="handleClick0()">Sequential</button>
<span id="s0"></span>
<br>
<button onclick="handleClick1()">Delayed</button>
<span id="s1"></span>
```

You should post minimal code to demonstrate the issue. The OP is way too much.

Comment: I tried using the delay option but once the condition for victory is met it alerts three time, one for each block of the game.

Comment: @sanchitarora—then you have other issues, so post another question. Reduce your code to the minimum required first.

Comment: I have corrected the post properly. Please suggest a possible solution.